# Which one is better Otto or Eventbus ?

Tags: netty, nio, otto, greenrobot-eventbus

I am planning to use event based solution to decouple few aspects in an android Application.

This application involves connecting to multiple sockets and receiving events from them asynchronously.

I am planning to use Netty NIO for handling these multiple socket connections which can produce events randomly independent of each other.

Keeping in mind, the ease of implementation,scalability and maintainability what would you suggest.

Comment: I use Otto in a project, it's simple, I'm happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using GreenRobot, and it works very good. Here is a comparaison: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/COMPARISON.md from GreenRobot.

- I use StickyEvent that are not available (as far I know in otto).
- I also know that Square provides a AndroidStudio for debugging, that could be a +
- Eventbus has not been updated since almost one year, but it seems greenRobot still answer some questions.